# How do i make my variables not retain their value after executing?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm creating a menu for a school project and the menu is supposed to run continuously until the user selects the exit choice but the problem is that if the user selects an option after another option it adds the value of the previous option to the current one and continues to repeat itself. The only way it ever brings out the correct values is if the option is run first. So i wanna know if there is a way to make a variable not retain its vale

```
int main()
{
int choice, sum = 0, n, num, count = 0, a;


do {
    cout << "1. Sum of first 10 natural numbers" << endl;
    cout << "2. Sum of n natural numbers" << endl;
    cout << "3. Prime number check" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice" << endl;
    cin >> choice;


    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
                sum += i;
            }
            cout << "Sum of first 10 natural numbers =" << sum << endl;
            break;
        }

        case 2: {
                cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
            cin >> n;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
                sum += i;
            }
            cout << "Sum of first " << n << "natural numbers =" << sum << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            cout << "Enter number to be checked : ";
            cin >> num;
            if (num == 0 || num < 0) {
                cout << "\n" << num << " is not prime." << endl;
            }
            else {
                for (a = 2; a < num; a++)
                    if (num % a == 0)
                        count++;
            }
            if (count > 1)
                cout << "\n" << num << " is not prime." << endl;
            else
                cout << "\n" << num << " is prime." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
} while (choice < 4);
}
```

so if i select option 2 and i input 5 the code produces the correct answer as 15 but if i select option 2 and input 5 again it produces 30 and if i do it again it produces 45. Same goes for the other. It adds the previous result to the current result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't resetting your sum variable to zero before/after you do your calculation so it will continue to accumulate. Try sum = 0 before your switch statement.

```
cout << "Enter your choice" << endl;
cin >> choice;

sum = 0;

switch (choice)
{
```

Comment: Also, do you think you could help with the prime number check. Most of the checks I've been seeing online all use bools so i thought i should try it out without using bools but its not working as i want it to.

Comment: Glad you solved it @Beloved.  May I offer another suggestion to help with cleaner code?  Instead of using global variables to do all your work, consider isolating functionality by writing functions such as sumTenNumers(), sumNNaturalNumbers(), etc.  Move the corresponding logic from your switch statement into those functions, call the functions from the switch and output the results.  The variables that you use in the functions (e.g. sum) will be *local in scope*, so you'll avoid the trap you fell into here.  Plus, it's good coding practice to segregate your logic in this way.  Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help